# Covariance of two Ito / Diffusion processes

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $B_t$ denote the standard Brownian motion process. $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are Ito diffusions with the following SDEs:
\begin{align}
dX_t &= \mu(t,X_t) \; dt + \sigma(t,X_t) \; dB_t \\
dY_t &= \mu(t,Y_t) \; dt + \sigma(t,Y_t) \; dB_t
\end{align}
What approach do I need to use to compute covariance of $X_t$ and $Y_t$? I tried to work with the associated integral equations of the above SDEs but that became too messy and did not make any sense.

I would appreciate any pointers and hints.

Comment: What exactly was getting messy? The best approach depends on your background, so it would be helpful to know a bit more about your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: I see; so you were just trying to multiply the stuff. Well, that's not the best way to tackle it. Try to apply Itô's formula to $f(x,y) := x \cdot y$ and the process $(X_t,Y_t)$.

Comment: So for instance I do not know how to simplify this term $\mathbb{E}[ \int\limits_0^t \mu(t, X_t) dt \int\limits_0^t \sigma(t, Y_t) dB_t]$?

Comment: I tried to use the Ito's product rule which is I guess what you are suggesting. But I run into a term like this $\mathbb{E}[ \int\limits_0^t X dY]$ and if I plug in the SDE for dY, no simplification is gained. It'll only get messier!

Comment: Well, no, when you plug in the the SDE for $dY_t$, you will get two terms: $$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t X_s \mu(s,Y_s) \, ds \right) \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t X_s \sigma(s,Y_s) \, dB_s \right).$$ You can't do anything about the first one, but the second one actually equals zero.

Comment: I do not see why the second term equals zero? I am thinking of the discretized approximation of the integral and it is unclear to me how $\mathbb{E}[X_s \sigma(s,Y_s) dB_s] = 0$. Is it due to independent increment property of Brownian motion?

Comment: For "well-behaved" functions $f$ the expectation of the stochastic integral $$M_t = \int_0^t f(s) \, dB_s$$ equals zero; this follows from the fact that $(M_t)_t$ is a martingale and, hence, in particular $\mathbb{E}(M_t)=\mathbb{E}(M_0)=0$.

Comment: if $f(s)$ is a stochastic function, as it is in the case in point ($f(s, X_s, Y_s) = X_s \sigma(s, Y_s)$), will this still hold?

Comment: Yes, it does... you need some integrability conditions on $\mu$ and $\sigma$ but you will need them anyway in order to make sense of the stochastic integrals in your SDE.

Comment: I've been using this comment thread (thanks!) but not sure where to proceed from here... with all the above, 1) Ito product rule gives $\mathbb{E}[dXdY] =  \mathbb{E}[d(XY)] +  \mathbb{E}[EdY] +  \mathbb{E}[YdX]$, then 2) $ \mathbb{E}[XdY] =   \mathbb{E}[X\mu_Ydt] = \mu_y dt \mu_x t =  \mathbb{E}[YdX]$ so we conclude that $ \mathbb{E}[dXdY] =  \mathbb{E}[d(XY)] + 2\mu_x \mu_y t dt$... How does one proceed then? (i.e. how to deal with $ \mathbb{E}[d(XY)]$?)